# install packages in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

Before to ask your help I search on StackOverflow for a possible solution. Unfortunately, they do not work for me.
I want to run an app in Rstudio. Most of the packages run for R>4.0 but BiocInstaller(that I need because is an old app) running R 3.5-3.99 .....
What I should do. If I install R >4 I have a problem with BiocInstaller. If I install R 3.5.3 I have a problem with other packages....please help
I tried fresh installing, upgrades, downgrades, installing in different ways manually and not...please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
if(!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)){
  install.packages("BiocManager")
}
BiocManager::install(version = "3.11")
```

See the [Bioconductor - install](https://www.bioconductor.org/install/) page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I allready tried and i take 2 errors. 1)Error: Bioconductor version '3.11' requires R version '4.0'; see https://bioconductor.org/install
( i have version 4)  2)package ‘BiocInstaller’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Comment: @Adam Try, for instance, `version = "3.08"`. Or `"3.07"`, see the [Boiconductor releases](https://www.bioconductor.org/about/release-announcements/).

Comment: thank you. I follow version 3.10 . I receive 16 warnings like   Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’
Warning: restored ‘digest’      Please what I should do with thems

Comment: @Adam See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922418/error-in-install-packages-cannot-remove-prior-installation-of-package-dbi), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439034/8245406).

Comment: Thank you. This I done and reinstall but still i getting the error    Error: With R version 3.5 or greater, install Bioconductor packages using BiocManager; see https://bioconductor.org/install    I follow what you told me exactly but seems like I have never done.....

Comment: @Adam In Bioconductor releases, link in my 2nd comment, it is said that R3.5 needs BiocManager 3.07 or 3.08. Have you tried those?